# htaccess RewriteCond issue

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

What Is wrong with this format ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^5. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^23.27. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^221.232.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website/junk/ [R]
```

the idea as you can imagine, is to redirect users whos ip starts with 5. or 23.27. 
or 221.232. to the website/junk/ folder, and i would need to add more ranges to this.
the problem im having with the above is that it also redirects my own ip which starts with like 24. 
 telling me something is wrong with the format and probably not catching just the first set of numbers 
yes i realize I am after ranges,and not single ip addresses, but its how i want it.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**DOT is a special character in regex that needs to be escaped otherwise it matches any character**

So `^5.` may also match `5.3.2.1` OR `50.40.30.20`

Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^5\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^23\.27\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^221\.23\.
RewriteRule ^ http://www.website/junk/ [L,R]
```

Comment: But why is it matching the IP that starts with `24.` in the original post?

Comment: `IP that starts with 24` shouldn't have matched but I haven't seen all the code. There may be other rules there, not sure.

Comment: thanks, if i get that right it could have been any sequence in my ip that got caught since i did not escape the ones listed. being new to all this and just using other found codes as examples tends to cause issues if you do not know how to format it properly.